# Tell unicode-math how to translate unicode symbols (script vs calligraphic)

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

I am using LuaLaTeX and unicode-math in my documents. I input most of the simple symbols (sum, products, greek letters, quantification, etc.) directly in unicode (using agda-mode for emacs). When I input the unicode character "SCRIPT CAPITAL L" (U+2112), I get in the pdf the equivalent of a `\mathscr L`. How can I tell the package unicode-math that I would like to have a `\mathcal L` instead whenever it encounters a unicode character U+2112?

Ideally, I would like to just pass an option to the package so that all "SCRIPT ..." uses `\mathcal ...` instead of `\mathscr ...`

**EDIT.** To clarify, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math Regular}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={\mathscr}]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range={\mathcal}]

\begin{document}
Unicode input: $ℒ$

Mathcal input: $\mathcal L$

Mathscr input: $\mathscr L$
\end{document}
```

The pdf output 3 different Ls, which leads me to believe that the unicode input actually uses `\mathscr` of `Libertinus Math Regular` in that example. How to I tell the package that I want it to use `\mathcal` from `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` when it encounters a U+2212 in the source?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you misunderstood my problem. I do have both fonts, using `range` indeed, and I do get different outputs if I use `\mathscr L` and `\mathcal L` in my source. But when I input the unicode character ℒ in my source, the output in the pdf looks like if I had typed `\mathscr L` in the source, and I would like the output in the pdf to look like if I had typed `\mathcal L` in the source.

Comment: Unicode specifies U+2212 (ℒ)  may be in either style depending on the font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So if I have `\setmathfont{Math Font 1}[range={\mathcal}]` and `\setmathfont{Math Font 2}[range={\mathscr}]` in my preamble, how does unicode-math decide if U+2212 will use `Math Font 1` or `Math Font 2`? I don't find the information in the documentation of the package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited with a MWE and real fonts.

Comment: Try swapping the input order of `\setmathfont` ranges for Latin Modern and Pagella.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Doesn't change a thing on my side. Does it on yours?

Comment: I didn't actually try it, but now I have.  Unfortunately, the system I'm working on apparently doesn't have a compatible version of LuaLaTeX; it crashes with `Failed to load "fontloader" module "basics-gen".` on trying to process `\documentclass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`range` is a bit temperamental, and script and calligraphic being the same Unicode range makes it more interesting, but

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math Regular}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range=cal]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=scr]

\AtBeginDocument{
\Umathcode"2112= "0 4 "2112
}

\begin{document}
Unicode input: $ℒ$

Mathcal input: $\mathcal L$

Mathscr input: $\mathscr L$

$ℒ$ $\mathcal L $ $\mathscr L$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I will have to do it on a letter basis. That's fine, I usually only use a small number, but I would definitely have expected unicode-math to have some kind of option for that!

Comment: @Pece unicode-math has the list of code points for each alphabet (used for `range`) so it could make  a loop for those Umathode but i don't think it does. You could make a feature  request at unicode-math github